# How to remount a disk that goes into read-only mode without rebooting?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I have a kernel bug that makes my SSD go into read-only mode. To fix this I have to reboot the system, do `fsck /dev/nvme0n1p2`, and then reboot again to make everything work.

Instead of doing the reboot, I tried to just do

```
sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p2
```

but how can I mount the `nvme0n1p2` disk without rebooting? I want to work on my machine without needing to reboot.

I tried:

```
lz@blade:~$ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2
mount: /: /dev/nvme0n1p2 already mounted on /.
```

So I tried:

```
lz@blade:~$ sudo umount /dev/nvme0n1p2
lz@blade:~$ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2
mount: /: /dev/nvme0n1p2 already mounted on /.
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Also, disks go read-only for a reason.  You should definitely look into why that's happening.  syslog is your friend.

Comment: [Did you tried `blockdev --setrw`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74091/209677)?

Comment: Are you sure it is not the SSD going into the "I am dying" mode, making it read only so you can rescue stuff?

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen I tried another brand new SSD and the same problem happens, and also other people have this problem

Answer (score 4):

From [Linux, how to change HDD state from ReadOnly after temporarly crash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74090/linux-how-to-change-hdd-state-from-readonly-after-temporarly-crash) the accepted answer (with 12 upvotes, at the time of this writing) states:

> try with `blockdev --setrw` or `hdparm -r 0`

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try this:

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/nvme0n1p2
```

It works fine for me.

If you find anything please let me know.

-Karmdip Joshi

Comment: sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/nvme0n1p2
mount: /: cannot remount /dev/nvme0n1p2 read-write, is write-protected.